# Plotting a constant text on a graph in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, text

I'm sure I'm probably asking a dumb question but couldn't find another the same as mine.

My friend helped my write a code to analyse give data and plot it with a trendline, I'd like to add a line of text in the top right of the graph with the other things printed on the graph that says what file it is (which is written as a constant elsewhere in the code).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from numpy import exp, loadtxt, pi, sqrt, random, linspace
from lmfit import Model
import glob, os

## Define gaussian
def gaussian(x, amp, cen, wid):
    """1-d gaussian: gaussian(x, amp, cen, wid)"""
    return (amp / (sqrt(2*pi) * wid)) * exp(-(x-cen)**2 / (2*wid**2))

## Define exponential decay
def expdecay(x, t, A): 
     return A*exp(-x/t)

## Define constants
fileToRun = 'Run15'
folderId = '\\'
baseFolder = 'C:'+folderId+'Users'+folderId+'ControlRoom6'+folderId+'Documents'+folderId+'PhD'+folderId+'Ubuntu-Analysis-DCF'+folderId+'DCF-an-b+decay'+folderId+'dcp-ap-27Al'+folderId+''
prefix = 'DECAY_COINC'
stderrThreshold = 10
minimumAmplitude = 0.1
approxcen = 780
MaestroT = 18

## Define paramaters
amps = []; ampserr = []; ts = []
folderToAnalyze = baseFolder + fileToRun + '\\'

## Gets number of files
files = []
os.chdir(folderToAnalyze)
for file in glob.glob(prefix + "*.Spe"):
    files.append(file)
numfiles = len(files)
if numfiles<=1:
    print('numfiles is {0}, minimum of 2 is required'.format(numfiles))
    raise SystemExit(0)

## Generate the time array

for n in range(0, numfiles):

    ## Print progress
    print('\rFile {0} / {1}'.format(n+1, numfiles), end='')

    ## Load text file
    x = np.linspace(0, 8191, 8192) 
    fullprefix = folderToAnalyze + prefix + str(n).zfill(3)
    y = loadtxt(fullprefix + ".Spe", skiprows= 12, max_rows = 8192) 

    ## Make figure
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,8))
    fig.suptitle('Coincidence Detections', fontsize=20)
    plt.xlabel('Bins', fontsize=14)
    plt.ylabel('Counts', fontsize=14)

    ## Plot data
    ax.plot(x, y, 'bo')
    ax.set_xlim(600,1000)

    ## Fit data to Gaussian
    gmodel = Model(gaussian)
    result = gmodel.fit(y, x=x, amp=8, cen=approxcen, wid=1)

    ## Plot results and save figure
    ax.plot(x, result.best_fit, 'r-', label='best fit')
    ax.legend(loc='best')
    texttoplot = result.fit_report()
    ax.text(0.02, 0.5, texttoplot, transform=ax.transAxes)
    plt.close()
    fig.savefig(fullprefix + ".png", pad_inches='0.5')

    ## Print progress
    if n==numfiles-1:
        print('\rDone')

    ## Append to list if error in amplitude and amplitude itself is within reasonable bounds
    if result.params['amp'].stderr < stderrThreshold and result.params['amp'] > minimumAmplitude:
        amps.append(result.params['amp'].value) 
        ampserr.append(result.params['amp'].stderr) 
        ts.append(MaestroT*n)

## Plot decay curve
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.errorbar(ts, amps, yerr= 2*np.array(ampserr), fmt="ko-", capsize = 5, capthick= 2, elinewidth=3, markersize=5)
plt.xlabel('Time', fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel('Peak amplitude', fontsize=14)

## Fit decay curve
emodel = Model(expdecay)
decayresult = emodel.fit(amps, x=ts, weights=1/np.array(ampserr), t=150, A=140)
ax.plot(ts, decayresult.best_fit, 'r-', label='best fit')

## Add text to plot
plottext = '{filetoRun}\n'
plottext = 'N: {0} / {1}\n'.format(len(ts), numfiles)
plottext += 't: {0:.2f} ± {1:.2f}\n'.format(decayresult.params['t'].value, decayresult.params['t'].stderr)
plottext += 'A: {0:.2f} ± {1:.2f}\n'.format(decayresult.params['A'].value, decayresult.params['A'].stderr)
plottext += 'Reduced $χ^2$: {0:.2f}\n'.format(decayresult.redchi)
ax.text(0.5, 0.55, plottext, transform=ax.transAxes, fontsize=14)
plt.show()

## Save figure
fig.savefig(folderToAnalyze + "A_" + prefix + "_decayplot.pdf", pad_inches='0.5')
```

I'd like it (in this case, Run15 to show just above where it says 'N = 28/50' in this plot). 
I've tried various combinations of brackets and plt.text, but honestly I don't really know what I'm doing and this is all new to me. It doesn't present an error like this, just outputs the graph without the desired text

[image: Output Graph]

Comment: Why do you put brackets around `filetoRun` ? try this : `plottext = filetoRun + '\n'`

Comment: Honestly, I just tried a bunch of different things, with (), with {}, with [], with /n, with '', and without all of those. using plt.text. Like I said, I don't really know what I'm doing, trying to pick it up by example and friendly assistance where possible :-)

Comment: NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-50-089283cca992> in <module>
     95 
     96 ## Add text to plot
---> 97 plottext = filetoRun + '\n'
     98 plottext = 'N: {0} / {1}\n'.format(len(ts), numfiles)
     99 plottext += 't: {0:.2f} ± {1:.2f}\n'.format(decayresult.params['t'].value, decayresult.params['t'].stderr)

NameError: name 'filetoRun' is not defined


^^^This is what I getting with plottext = filetoRun + '\n' on Line 97 instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you made a mistake using `=` instead of `+=`, and that's what fails to print your first line with `fileToRun`.

Other than that, your intuition on bringing brackets `'{filetoRun}\n'` around a variable within a string makes sense: that's the purpose of Python f-strings! You just need to use a `f` specifier before the string.

Replace this:

```
plottext = '{fileToRun}\n'
plottext = 'N: {0} / {1}\n'.format(len(ts), numfiles)
```

By this:

```
plottext = f'{fileToRun}\n'
plottext += 'N: {0} / {1}\n'.format(len(ts), numfiles)
```

Nice plot by the way!

Comment: Still no luck I'm afraid:
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-59-fcf0ea66d2a1> in <module>
     95 
     96 ## Add text to plot
---> 97 plottext = f'{filetoRun}\n'
     98 plottext = 'N: {0} / {1}\n'.format(len(ts), numfiles)
     99 plottext += 't: {0:.2f} ± {1:.2f}\n'.format(decayresult.params['t'].value, decayresult.params['t'].stderr)

NameError: name 'filetoRun' is not defined

Comment: Also, thanks for the compliments on the plot. Afraid I can't take all the credit, or much of it, lol. I just 'designed' it, another guy coded most of it

Comment: Look at the error, it says `filetoRun is not defined`: how is that possible while you defined it just above using `fileToRun = 'Run15'`? Did you run all over again?

Comment: It was the t in 'filestoRun', it should've been 'filesToRun'. Coupled with the += on Line 98 and f-string that you suggested!

Comment: Haha yes well seen, edited that in my response. You may accept my answer!

Comment: Ha! thanks, was just about to ask if you minded doing that!

Comment: Yay. Please, in your next question try to isolate exactly what's wrong. That'll maybe help you debug and find the solution by your own, and definitely will help SO users to help you. Here, for instance, the problem lies obviously in the text plotting part: we don't necessarily need to see all the surroundings (model, and even the other parts of the plot). Best is to reproduce the bug with a minimal example.

Comment: Yeh, my bad. Honestly, I probably new the problem was between the definition and that bit near Line 97, but was worried by not including the surrounding code, I'd omit something that was the problem that I hadn't suspected. Regardless, I'll try to reduce the amount of code by interpretting the error - it is something I struggle with, I am saddened to admit.